# How can I read any kind of File as Binary value ?

Tags: qt

If I want to get binary value from files no matter which format they have, how may I do that ?
I have tried this code but it only can read text files line by line, nothing more than that.

```
QFile file(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName (this, tr("Open File"),
                                         "",tr("")));
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly ))
        return ;
int size = file.size();
qDebug()<<size;
while (!file.atEnd()) {
      QByteArray line = file.readLine();
      qDebug()<<line;
```

Comment: You just can't read lines, but instead of it, whole blocks of data.

Comment: can you tell me how I might I do that to read whole block of data ?

Comment: read( qint64 maxSize ) oraz readAll()

Answer (score 2):

Allocate a buffer to read data into and use QFile::read function. For example:

```
qint64 bufSize = 1024;
char *buf = new char[bufSize];
qint64 dataSize;
while (!file.atEnd()) {
    dataSize = file.read(buf, bufSize);
    /* process data */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read not only in array of char, but also into other types. For example reading structure from file:

```
struct Foo
{
  int bar;
  long foobar;
}
//...
Foo foo1;
file.read(foo1, sizeof(Foo));
```